# Output power vs idle power of an audio amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio, power-dissipation

Let's say I have a AB class power amplifier that is able to give an average output power of `30W` on a `6 ohm` loudspeaker. Now in general, how much power should the amplifier dissipate when there is no signal applied?

I am asking this because I have an amplifier that dissipates about `Vdc*Idc =30W` when it is idle. The maximum amplitude (when clipping starts) of the output signal is `20V` on a load of `6 ohm` and with Ltspice I found that the maximum output power `v(t)*i(t)` is about `66W` and the average power is about `30W`. To me it seems like the amplifier dissipates too much when idle, doesn't it?

Comment: Depends on the internal construction. Remember that the output needs to be held at half the supply through the output stage. This is not cheap.

Comment: How did you measure the dissipation?

Comment: @pipe I multiplied the voltage of the power supply with the current it is supplying when no signal is applied. `P = Vcc*Iidle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the power level where the amp transitions from Class A to Class B modes of operation, i.e. where the inactive transistor cuts off.

There is a conflict between efficiency (transition to Class B at very low power, at the risk of some crossover distortion) and sound quality (high idle power, where the amplifier may remain in Class A up to 5 or 10W).

Many of the "Class AB" amplifiers seen online are [practically Class B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplifier#Class_AB) and will show some crossover distortion as designed, as they are designed such that both output transistors are not "on" simultaneously. (Note that the [Wikipedia description of Class B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplifier#Class_B) may be true for RF amplifiers but disagrees with 80 years of actual [Class B audio amplifier design](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_DJZf2P0gFoC&pg=PA255&lpg=PA255&dq=PX4%20circuit%20Class%20B&source=bl&ots=99Wq5xPg0p&sig=etyYhI9iFsbYY81PEHbpnbfqn-Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiehqPewtHKAhVCcg8KHaSOASIQ6AEIPjAF#v=onepage&q=Class%20B&f=false) (p.49 of link)).

Some amplifiers allow adjusting the quiescent (idle) current via a pot - see RV24 on [this schematic](http://paul-kemble.tripod.com/sound8h.html) - after assembly and after replacing a transistor, you measure the output stage current and adjust the pot for 20mA (or other recommended figure). study the circuit for yours and see if this is possible.

TL/DR Your idle power is on the high side, but not unrealistic for a Class AB amp designed for higher quality. If it's adjustable it may simply be maladjusted, or "tweaked" in an attempt to reduce distortion.

Comment: I disagree. A completely unbiased push-pull stage will actually be in class C, and it is *this* condition that delivers the crossover distortion. I bias class B amps with a distortion analyser, and the transition from Class C to Class B is clearly visible: the spikes disappear into the noise. Increasing the bias further into Class AB increases heat but does not reduce the distortion any further. I would need to see some actual evidence that the stage is really in Class AB when the spikes disappear. Naturally I am using the RF conduction-angle class definitions here.